# If or Is Statement in SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, svn

Looking to solve this.

Column of revision numbers which use alpha numeric.  want to use calculated field when revision =*OBS or *SUP to show true.  I used originally when only one revision type

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OBS "," "&Revision&" "))

Now I need to do the same with the two revision types.  I have tried OR statements but it makes all my other revision Yes which is the opposite.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: where did you apply the `OR` maybe it should look like this: `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OBS "," "&Revision&" ")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*SUP "," "&Revision&" ")))`

Comment: You solved the issue!!!  Thank you so much it was the placement of the OR, now if i could recoup the 2hrs of playing around in excel!